# Sending Push Notification to Multiple GCM Ids returning error: MISSING_REGISTRATIONS

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notifications to multiple devices using google cloud messaging. Below is the JSON Data which I am sending:

```
{"to":["APA91bHMvoTuEYQAGwgB7Q-Em8j4DyZOrGXZJ9uTyFhddojDFHr0VeZUHAEgw_kk6QFmKQoWe6oN2fIgDAw9AoPigCqZ4BaMlNzxqWoBRx6Q3ZBBKTinzqUj8F7BEA5ZHmCIArsEB3zT","APA91bE4mP2TscsMf4IJT9-o70YSFPMo34NGGG4IXS4Oe9uuHawxTGplqd017NiGXC5ftlIUaXIIkI60nR7w5GI1UPy5IdqYDPt0_C1TW5S5o1zaGKfv9CKtb6CV3cDc1cvEKyCeMwUe3NZpX4UmhIGJfEmetQUNgg","APA91bHwfnK5l6CbHe_2SddBSHPJmuOxI0AapbyXAbuMVktFIICJx6WTu44ElkuxoBd70rsmdrdGSV7r9hDFvW-cBynunqOJAhI8PhKjDd2hINU91vP4_6yWRtRN2PYCXwkhkKxORrPcMi7pezt8FGhmynznIJpW9A"],"delay_while_idle":true,"collapse_key":"sample","delivery_receipt_requested":true,"data":{"message":"Stuffed Aloo Curry with Gatta Pulao by Chef Shelly","title":"Today's Special","request_type":"promotion"},"message_id":"m-313e76a8-b42c-4a8c-a1d4-ad58a059494a","time_to_live":10000}
```

I am not able to send push message and I am getting below message in return

```
<success xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"></success>
<iq id='e0nLC-0' type='result'><bind xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind'><jid>170453453515@gcm.googleapis.com/SmackAA9F4121</jid></bind></iq>
<iq id='e0nLC-1' type='result'></iq>
<message><gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">{&quot;message_id&quot;:&quot;m-313e76a8-b42c-4a8c-a1d4-ad58a059494a&quot;,&quot;from&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;error_description&quot;:&quot;InvalidJson: MISSING_REGISTRATIONS : Missing \&quot;to\&quot; field\nJSON_TYPE_ERROR : Field \&quot;to\&quot; must be a JSON java.lang.String: [\&quot;APA91bHMvoTuEYQAGwgB7Q-Em8j4DyZOrGXZJ9uTyFhddojDFHr0VeZUHAEgw_kk6QFmKQoWe6oN2fIgDAw9AoPigCqZ4BaMlNzxqWoBRx6Q3ZBBKTinzqUj8F7BEA5ZHmCIArsEB3zT\&quot;,\&quot;APA91bE4mP2TscsMf4IJT9-o70YSFPMo34NGGG4IXS4Oe9uuHawxTGplqd017NiGXC5ftlIUaXIIkI60nR7w5GI1UPy5IdqYDPt0_C1TW5S5o1zaGKfv9CKtb6CV3cDc1cvEKyCeMwUe3NZpX4UmhIGJfEmetQUNgg\&quot;,\&quot;APA91bHwfnK5l6CbHe_2SddBSHPJmuOxI0AapbyXAbuMVktFIICJx6WTu44ElkuxoBd70rsmdrdGSV7r9hDFvW-cBynunqOJAhI8PhKjDd2hINU91vP4_6yWRtRN2PYCXwkhkKxORrPcMi7pezt8FGhmynznIJpW9A\&quot;]&quot;,&quot;error&quot;:&quot;INVALID_JSON&quot;,&quot;message_type&quot;:&quot;nack&quot;}</gcm></message>
```

If I send push using single gcmId as String, it works fine. But if I send it to list of gcmIds, I get Error response:

> "MISSING_REGISTRATIONS : Missing \"to\" field\nJSON_TYPE_ERROR : Field \"to\" must be a JSON java.lang.String"

Answer (score 0):

You should use the old "registration_ids" parameter instead of "to" when sending multiple registration IDs.

> to - This parameter specifies the recipient of a message. The value
>   must be a registration token or notification key.
>
> registration_ids - This parameter specifies a list of devices
>   (registration tokens, or IDs) receiving a multicast message. It must
>   contain at least 1 and at most 1000 registration IDs. Multicast
>   messages (sending to more than 1 registration IDs) are allowed using
>   HTTP JSON format only.

[(Source)](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref#table1)

It's also mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server#implement-send-request) :

> Though for general purposes it is deprecated, you can use registration_ids as a target for multicast messages to more than one device (up to 1000).

Comment: Already tried but registration_ids works with HTTP protocol.
I am using XMPP protocol

Comment: @amitmitra Are you using the XMPP protocol? XMPP doesn't support sending to multiple registration IDs (as you can see in the quote above - `Multicast messages (sending to more than 1 registration IDs) are allowed using HTTP JSON format only`).

Comment: Thanks Eran!
Doc suggest that for multicast messages I have to use Http Protocol.

Can anyone please suggest any link to implement GCM Server using Http protocol in java